# Using .xml configuration files in symfony 1.4

Tags: xml, configuration, symfony1

Is it possible to mix xml and yml files to configure symfony 1.4?

What i the structure of xml configuration files?

Can i convert yml to xml config files using a nifty tool?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only use yml configuration in symfony 1.x.